# Make new array from subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can you help figure out a recursive function that would remove a subarray from an array, then stores all of those arrays (including the original one) into a new array?

**For example**

```
var input = [1, 2, [[3,4], 5]]

    splitArray(input)
    output:  [
          [1, 2, [[3,4], 5]],
          [[3,4], 5],
          [5]
        ]
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: use .splice to split any array up.

Answer (score 0):

Looking a little bit closer, I guess what you really need is this solution.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
alert(myFunction(fruits,fruits.length-1));

function myFunction(arrayF,val) {
    if(val!=0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<val;i++)
            arrayF[arrayF.length]=arrayF[i];
        myFunction(arrayF,val-1);
    }
    return arrayF;       
}
```